# CSS - Keep children inside container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit 2 children inside a container without them overflowing.
Here is an example of my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/195em81t/

I want it so that if `#footer` is present it will take 20% of the container and `#content` will fill the other 80% and add a scroll bar if necessary.

I don't want to set a hard 80% height on `#content` as sometimes `#footer` won't be present in which case I want `#content` to take 100% of the height;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox. By using `flex-grow` property, flex items can grow to fill remaining space.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 80%; /* Start at 80%, then grow to fill remaining space */
  overflow: auto; /* In case contents are too tall */
}
.footer {
  flex: 20%; /* Start at 20%, then grow to fill remaining space */
  overflow: auto; /* In case contents are too tall */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>  Content<br>
  </div>
</div>
```